# Eclipse : Where to put NDK reference? Native Development is missing?

Tags: android, eclipse, reference, sdk, installation

I have to integrate some c code with my Android app. I did some R&D and came to know that I can do this through **NDK** (Native Development Kit).

I downloaded **NDK** and read some article and watched videos to Configure NDK but Android node in **Preferences** does not show **Native Development** node to set NDK reference.

Am I missing some step or any other problem... please help

see my preference Window.

[image]

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/25292915/3742271

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed [this guide](http://permadi.com/blog/2011/09/setting-up-android-jni-projects-in-windows-eclipse-and-sequoyah/) but when I installed the Sequoya packages it didn't work --no new options appeared on the Preferences or contextual menu.

I work over Ubuntu 10.10 so I tried adding these lines to .bashrc

```
# Android definitions
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/android-ndk-r7c
export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=$HOME/android-ndk-r7c
export NDK=$HOME/android-ndk-r7c
```

I re-started Eclipse and reinstalled the Sequoyah packages on Eclipse once again --which I never uninstalled, so that was a little bit weird. But it worked.

Perhaps if you have Windows you can try adding those as Enviroment Variables.

Answer (score 13):

While installing the ADT plugin as:

1. Help-> install new software.
2. Click Add
3. Name - ADT

   Repo - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ or find the link in here

   http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html
4. This is important. Select both **Developers tools** and **NDK plugins** and continue installation.

There you go. You can find the Option in Windows->Preferences->Android->NDK. Set the path accordingly

Comment: This is the only answer I've found that works every time this problem crops up on our developer computers.  This was how you used to have to install the NDK back before it was nicely bundled.  Here's hoping they keep the link active.

Answer (score 1):

For me the NDK path was missing because I had not installed the [Java Development Kit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).
Installing that and restarting eclipse caused the NDK link to appear in the menu

Answer (score 0):

I has same problem on Win7, Eclise Juno.

1. move/copy NDK, CDT features and plugin from /eclipse/ dir to some backup dir.
   files and dir mask: org.eclipse.cdt*; com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk*; 
   this will save time in reinstalation of NDK
2. in Eclipse uninstall Android Native Developer Tools 
   via Eclipse/Help/Install new Software/ already installed /...
   close eclipse
3. update environment variables:
   update PATH=$PATH:$HOME/android-ndk-r8c
   new ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=$HOME/android-ndk-r8c
   new NDK=$HOME/android-ndk-r8c
   same as mentioned by Marina
4. copy files and dirs from backup back to /eclipse/features & plugins
5. start eclipse and instal NDK again