# Eclipse Juno ADT plugin NDK path removed?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, adt

I can't find the option to set the NDK path on Eclipse Juno with the ADT plugin. (I downloaded yesterday the ADT Bundle from the Android site).

Everyone says I should find it under Windows -> Preferences -> Android -> NDK but the option NDK under Android simply does not exists. Maybe they changed it's location in the recent version? Anyway I can't seem to find a way to change the NDK path in my Eclipse.

Picture:
[image]

I'm feeling like I'm missing something really obvious here...

Comment: Try to reinstall ADT bundle in new directory. BTW, make sure that none of paths (to **ADT**, **SDK**, and **NDK**) does not contain spaces _(your `D:\Program Files (x86)\Android` may cause various strange problems)_.

Comment: I tried to do that but I think it solved other problem I had, this problem however it did not fix. I ended up adding manually the NDK_PATH to the system enviroment variables.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you need re-install the `ADT-23.0.4.zip` (Don't forget select the Android Native Development Tools);
[Please have a look at this Android SDK page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Troubleshooting).

You should:

1. Download ADT-23.0.4.zip.
2. Just re-install.
3. Restart.
4. You will see Eclipse > Window > Android > NDK tag.

Comment: Didn't help fro me )=

Comment: Is there a way to update this in existing eclipse adt installation?

Answer (score 26):

Fix this problem by install 'Developer Tools'

From Eclipse -> Help -> Install New Software... ->

select: "Android Developer Tools Update Site - https://dl.google.com/android/eclipse/"

uncheck "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" option

check and install "Developer Tools"

Comment: What did the trick for me was to uncheck "Contact all update sites". Otherwise it kept failing with an unhelpful error...

Comment: +1 for uncheck "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" option

Comment: This is the correct answer.  I wish they let you select the directory without having to explicitly install NDK support, but this was easy enough.

Comment: I forget that NDK is not installed in my mac. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same problem. It was annoying to waste those few hours, but I guess I figured it out.
What I did was,

1. Grabbed the file `com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk_22.3.0.v201310242005-887826.jar` from the older ADT installation I had, which showed the NDK option from the `\eclipse\plugins` folder.
2. Renamed it to `com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk_23.0.2.1259578.jar`.
3. Pasted it in `adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\eclipse\plugins`
4. Restarted Eclipse.
5. Hi NDK!

I hope this won't cause any problems in the future!

Comment: Great man ! You saved my day ! Thanks for sharing the answer to the world my saviour !

Comment: How odd. That file is completely missing from the adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip version of eclipse. Copying it from the old version does seem to fix things. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After:

1. Closing Eclipse Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1) for Mac OS X.
2. Installing Oracle Java JDK 1.7 (JDK 7u75) (jdk-7u75-macosx-x64.dmg)
3. Modifying Eclipse.ini to add the two lines (right before -vmargs):
   -vm
   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
4. Restarting Eclipse.
5. Going to Preferences->Java->Installed JREs, clicking "Search", and selecting Java SE 7 (1.7.0_75) as the default JRE
6. Restarting Eclipse

The Preferences->Android->NDK setting appeared and I was able to set the NDK path.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, i dont know why, but the problems is with the Eclipse/Juno version,  so i download in the eclipse page the Kepler versión and  install the pluggin of adt, And all works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with the latest Eclipse Luna and the ADT plugin - it turned out despite both the CDT and Android Native Developer Tools plugins being installed in Eclipse Luna they were not working.

The cause was that I was using the Apple Java 1.6 (which is Java 6), and Luna "requires" a Java 7 VM. No warnings were provided though! To solve it I installed the latest JDK from Oracle, and then updated the Eclipse.ini file inside the Eclipse.app bundle, adding the 2 lines:

```
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

just before the line that is `-vmargs`.

Then when I restarted Eclipse, the CDT was correctly being used `Eclipse -> Preferences...` listed some C++ settings that were not previously there, and the Android section had an NDK entry the allowed to specify the path.