# Where specify NDK in July 2, 2014 ADT eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I just downloaded the Android SDK which has the filename adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip and deleted my old workspace to get a clean state.

When I startup Eclipse, go to Preferences/Android, I no longer see the NDK section where I can specify the path for the NDK.

Did this section get moved?

Comment: Separate download 4 ndk.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse Juno ADT plugin NDK path removed?] and _[Set Eclipse NDK Path Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723712/eclipse-juno-adt-plugin-ndk-path-removed)_

Comment: Answered in _[Where specify NDK in July 2, 2014 ADT eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743726/where-specify-ndk-i-july-2-2014-adt-eclipse)_

Comment: Yes, duplicate.  Didn't see other answer before.  Please mark as duplicate - thx!

Comment: As @dhakim mentioned, following steps [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has happened on two of the development computers so far.  It's a gigantic pain every time.  My workaround is to use the old plugin update site, that fixes it every time.

Do Help-Install New Software... and add the site https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
From there, select Android Native Development Tools.

This was the old mechanism for installing the NDK, back before everything was nicely packaged, and at some point they might remove the link, but for now it makes the NDK section appear again, at which point you can point it wherever you want, including at newly downloaded ndk folders.

Answer (score 4):

in the ADT independent package (http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-23.0.2.zip) i found the needed ndk plugin `com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk_23.0.2.1259578.jar`

but in adt bundle directory `adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\eclipse\plugins\`, there is no such file.

it works after i put the jar file in the plugins dir.

Is it a packaging error? I dont know. Pity it is wasting my time.

Comment: I have `com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk_23.0.0.1245622.jar`, but it doesn't help.

Comment: @AlexCohn maybe the jar and eclipse don't match? adt bundle has an eclipse juno (4.2). You should try the new ndk plugin.

Comment: I can confirm this works with Eclipse 4.2.1 (Juno) and ADT 23.0.4.