# Eclipse Kepler ADT plugin NDK path removed?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I can't find the option to set the NDK path on Eclipse Kepler with the ADT plugin. (I downloaded the ADT 23.0.4 Bundle from the Android site).

Please, don't close this question as duplicate, cause I tried all answers from SO:

1) Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24847374/1991579)

2) Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25032380/1991579)

3) Full reinstall ADT, C++ plugins etc.

Still don't see NDK tab in Windows -> Preferences -> Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Uninstall ALL plugins.

2) Install again.

3) Works fine.

Always have problems with plugin updates in Eclipse.