# Can't find the NDK tab

Tags: eclipse, windows, android-ndk, cygwin

I saw in some tutorial mention that we don't need to install cygwin after ndk 7. 
I had install the ndk 10, in tutorial it say we had the setup the ndk path in eclipse, the problems is i can't find ndk in my eclipse. 
[image]

& I NDK website also mention we need to install Cygwin 1.7 & higher.

So I confuse that do I still need to install Cygwin?
[image]

& Do I need to install GNU Make & Awk? The tutorial that I follow doesn't mention about this..

Answer (score 1):

You only need **cygwin** to use **ndk-gdb** for native debugging, which does not work well, anyway. Adapted versions of GNU Make & Awk are part of NDK distribution.

The missing setting in ADT is probably a bug in the recent version, see e.g. *[Set Eclipse NDK Path Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764460/set-eclipse-ndk-path-windows)* and *[Eclipse Juno ADT plugin NDK path removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723712/eclipse-juno-adt-plugin-ndk-path-removed)*

Comment: Yes. I miss to set the ADT, after install the ADT then the NDK appeared. Thanks.

Comment: What is _"miss to set the ADT"_? Can you give more detail?

Comment: Which mean after I install and setup the ADT bundle then have the ADT tag.. thx