# How to setup NDK and it's features into Eclipse ADT 23.0.1?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I Installed Eclipse ADT with the Android SDK(ADT 23.0.1 -http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702.zip) in Windows 8 Pc.**But there's no NDK path setup option.**

I am using this versions.

[image]

And also not showing NDK settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fallowed this and it's now works.(Re installed ADK http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Troubleshooting)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24847374/1641556

I have done this things to get back NDK settings.

- Download ADT latest
  version.(http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-23.0.2.zip)
- Just re-install.
- Restart.
     You will see Eclipse > Window > Android > NDK tag.

Answer (score 3):

Watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2onPuDZQVY
In this video give steps to install NDK in eclipse.

Go to Help --> install new Software -> Add

when click on Add one popup open
in that popup box paste this link(**if your eclipse version is helios**)
http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/helios

then click  on **Next** .
**after installing CDT plugins Restart Your Eclips**
[image]

For setup **NDK in eclipse** for **windows**

Go **Windows** tab -> **Preferances** --> **Android** --> **NDK**

Click on Browse Button And select **NDK APTH**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's the bug of eclipse in ADT. You just need to re-install ADT.
But I recommend you not to download ADT. It's much better to download a dedicated eclipse. And then install ADT plugin.